# ActiveRecord not behaving as I expect it

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby 2.0
Windows 8.1
Rails 4.1
MySQL2 gem

To avoid an error, I am using the following code to check for an existing payment, prior to creating a new payment record:

```
    payment = {"organization_id" => organization_id,
               "date" => row[1],
               "amount" => row[2],
               "description" => row[3]}
    slug = "#{organization_id.to_s}_#{row[1].to_s}_#{row[2].to_s}_#{row[3]})

    organization_payment = OrganizationPayment.where(:slug => slug)[0]
    if !organization_payment
      new_organization_payment = OrganizationPayment.create(payment)
    end
```

Every once in a while, I am getting the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error at /process_uploaded_payments_data
Duplicate entry 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' for key 'index_organization_payments_on_slug'
```

I also have the following in my model:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :slug
```

Is there any reason why the entry causing the duplicate error would not have been caught by the code above? Any ideas?

## Solution

I am still not certain what caused the problem, but I learned the hard way that validating uniqueness does not really work, if you also have a before_save call in your model that creates the slug in question. The workaround is an exception handler:

```
    begin
      new_organization_payment = OrganizationPayment.create(payment)
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
       next
    end
```

Comment: what is the value of `payment`, and `slug`?  Can we see the preceding code setting these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is your problem but a possible cause of this could be [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Example) -- when your code is running in a process it can be interrupted right after the if condition before it creates the new record.

Putting a unique constraint on the column in the database is a fine way of dealing with this problem, though. You can catch the exception and deal with it that way. You also don't have to manually check for the duplicity, you can use active record validations; fetching the entire record just to check if it exists is not the best practice anyway. More info:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of

Comment: I already have the following in my model: validates_uniqueness_of :slug

Comment: Then you don't need to check for it yourself, you can rely on the validation (and catch the exception if needed). The validation doesn't actually solve the race condition problems either, so if you are running this code in multiple processes you can run into duplicate records occasionally.

Comment: Unless Rails is creating a race condition, I am not doing it.